# Trigger keypresses from python in xbmc

Tags: raspberry-pi, keypress, xbmc

I am trying to trigger a return keypress, or left mouse button press from python to affect xbmc (raspbmc). I have previously done this in raspbian with `uinput`, but this doesn't seem to work for raspbmc. I have also tried with this script from adafruit https://learn.adafruit.com/retro-gaming-with-raspberry-pi/buttons which has also worked for me on raspbian.

Any help appreciated :)
Thanks
Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying seemingly every solution, using this python xbmc json module did the trick! Not quite a key press, but controls xbmc as if it were

https://github.com/jcsaaddupuy/python-xbmc

this is the code I modified to get GPIO input to trigger events in XBMC

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO  
from xbmcjson import XBMC
xbmc = XBMC("http://127.0.0.1/jsonrpc")
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)  

def my_callback2(channel):  
    global XBMC
    xbmc.Input.Select()

GPIO.add_event_detect(23, GPIO.FALLING, callback=my_callback2, bouncetime=300)  


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:  
        print "Waiting for rising edge on port 24"  
        GPIO.wait_for_edge(24, GPIO.RISING)  
        print "Rising edge detected on port 24. Here endeth the third lesson."  

    except KeyboardInterrupt:  
        GPIO.cleanup()       # clean up GPIO on CTRL+C exit  
    GPIO.cleanup()           # clean up GPIO on normal exit try:
```